# A lemma in Tensor Categories (Etingof et al)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, projective-module, monoidal-categories

Lemma 8.10.5 in EGNO's [*Tensor Categories*](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/egnobookfinal.pdf) basically states

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a tensor category over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{k}$ with braiding $c$.
> For any nonzero simple object $X$ the composition
> \begin{align}
>     t(X) := \operatorname{ev}_X \circ c_{X, X^\vee} \circ \operatorname{coev}_X \in \operatorname{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathbf{1}) 
> \end{align}
> is nonzero.

I feel very conflicted.
On the one hand, the one line proof given in the book seems plausible:

> Since $X$ is simple, the corresponding composition
> \begin{align}
> \operatorname{End}(\mathbf{1}) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf{1}, X\otimes X^\vee) \to \operatorname{End}(\mathbf{1})
> \end{align}
> consists of nonzero maps between 1-dimensional spaces, and is thus non-zero.

On the other hand, suppose that the lemma holds and that $X$ is projective.
Then $P = X \otimes X^\vee$ is projective.
Set $f = t(X)^{-1} \operatorname{coev}_X$ and $g = \operatorname{ev}_X \circ c_{X, X^\vee}  $.
But then
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{1} \xrightarrow{f} P \xrightarrow{g} \mathbf{1} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbf{1}}
\ ,
\end{align}
so that $\mathbf{1}$, being a direct summand in a projective, is projective.
But then $\mathcal{C}$ is semisimple.
A contradiction to the existence of non-semisimple finite tensor categories with simple projective objects.

Note that in fact the general heuristic in this last part implies that in a non-semisimple (finite) tensor category there exists no nonzero endomorphism of the tensor unit factoring through a projective object.
For this heuristic, see also the proof of Theorem 6.6.1 in the book.

So, where is the mistake?

---

**Edit:**

Here are two examples for non-semisimple finite tensor categories with simple projective objects:

- The [symplectic fermions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08164).
  This category is even factorizable, i.e. ribbon with a certain non-degeneracy condition on the braiding.
- The [category of representations over the restricted quantum group $\overline{U}_q(sl_2)$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0504093.pdf).

---

**Edit 2:**
The mistake is in the proof in the book.
Namely, as I prove, the map $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf{1}, X \otimes X^\vee) \to \operatorname{End}(\mathbf{1})$ is zero if $X$ is projective.

Comment: I don't know any examples of non-semisimple finite tensor categories with simple projective objects off the top of my head, but I think what you've written down is a proof by contradiction that no such thing can have a braiding, yes?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I added two examples. Unfortunately, one of the categories I list definitely is braided. So I have absolutely no idea what's going on :D

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Actually, there also exists a version of the second example where the coproduct is modified so that the category also becomes factorizable. Of course this is not twist equivalent to my example.

Comment: Please mail Etingof, who keeps a list of errata on his website.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I just did, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deceptively simple proof in the book indeed managed to deceive us.

How?
It assumes that the linear map
\begin{align}
    \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf{1}, X^\vee \otimes X) &\to \operatorname{End}(\mathbf{1}) \newline  
   f &\mapsto \operatorname{ev}_X \circ f
\end{align}
is non-zero, which is not true according to my proof above.